# How to remove python installed from source in Oracle Enterprise Linux 5.4

Tags: linux, python, uninstall, oracle-linux

I installed python 2.6.6, I already had python which is lower version 2.4 by default.
Now I want to remove the python 2.6.6 ? There is no uninstall target and remove procedures from the internet.

I google it out, but no results found for the OEL 5.4,

Comment: Search all the folders and executable related to python 2.6.6.
do an - "rm -rf <files/folder>" for the files and folders. That'll do

Comment: yeah done with a new prefix and deleted all those files. And also reinstalled the old version from yum which is by default.

Comment: Yeah my issue solved now, by installing the python in a prefix, I found which files to be deleted, next I deleted those files from the file-system, And I got command not found when executing python command in terminal, so to avoid any further issues to come, I re-installed the python which is in my yum list. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile python 2.6.6 again inside your home folder (with prefix flag) and look at the output. Then, delete the same files that are placed in the system folder.